# Agregar un guión cada 4 letras a una cadena

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como pasar de esto `76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1` a esto `76b9b85-0d598e7b-d89552056-e947a0c1` en javascript.

Esto es lo que he hecho

```
const agregarCaracter = (cadena, caracter, pasos) => {
    let cadenaConCaracteres = "";
    const longitudCadena = cadena.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < longitudCadena; i += pasos) {
        if (i + pasos < longitudCadena) {
            cadenaConCaracteres += cadena.substring(i, i + pasos) + caracter;
        } else {
            cadenaConCaracteres += cadena.substring(i, longitudCadena);
        }
    }
    return cadenaConCaracteres;
}
```

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues lo que has intentado.

Comment: ¿Cada 4 letras? No veo ningún patrón en tu salida. Los pedazos que separas no tienen 4 letras, el primero tiene dos letras, el segundo tiene tres. Por otro lado, el primer pedazo tiene 7 caracteres, el segundo 8 ¿que es lo que quieres exactamente? No se entiende tu problema.

Comment: Hola, stack me borra una parte del codigo, no se porque

Comment: `const agregarCaracter = (cadena, caracter, pasos) => {
    let cadenaConCaracteres = "";
    const longitudCadena = cadena.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < longitudCadena; i += pasos) {
        if (i + pasos < longitudCadena) {
            cadenaConCaracteres += cadena.substring(i, i + pasos) + caracter;
        } else {
            cadenaConCaracteres += cadena.substring(i, longitudCadena);
        }
    }
    return cadenaConCaracteres;
}`

Comment: Jaime Menendez, es un ejemplo hipotetico, asi es mas o menos lo que busco. No tienen que ser 4 tambien puedo poner cada 6 letras

Comment: Seria bueno que me ayudaran, no que me esten pidiendo coas que he hecho cuando claramente se muy poco de javascript.

Comment: @GOMobile si es hipotético dilo por favor. En tu título dices claramente 4 letras pero luego lo que dices que quieres es otra cosa. Acá te ayudamos, pero lo primero es redactar una buena pregunta. Checa si te sirve mi respuesta.

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta, disculpa si no me expresé bien, ya reviso.

Comment: Hmmm, no es agregar un `-` cada cuatro "letras"... ¿Qué trataste de decir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes separar tu string con ayuda del método substring simplemente iterando en tu cadena y contruyendo una nueva cadena con los grupos separados. Te adjunto una función ejemplo:

```js
function separarString(str, size) {
    let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += size) {
        result += str.substring(i, i + size) + "-";
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
}

console.log(separarString("76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1", 4));
console.log(separarString("76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1", 7));
```

Usando regex:

```js
function separarString(str, size) {
    const result = str.replace(new RegExp(`.{${size}}`, 'g'), '$&-');
    return result.substring(0, result.length % size === 0 ? result.length - 1 : result.length);
}

console.log(separarString("76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1", 4));
console.log(separarString("76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1", 5));
console.log(separarString("76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1", 6));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo sabia que encontraria la respuesta aquí,

Comment: @GOMobile con regex sería `const result = str.replace(/.{4}/g, '$&-');` por si quieres probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te pueda ayudar.

```
let cadenaCaracteres = "76b9b850d598e7bd89552056e947a0c1"

let cadenaConCaracteres= (string_) => {
    let longitudCadena = string_.length;

    //Validar que el total de caracteres de la cadena sea multiplo de 4
    if(longitudCadena % 4 == 0){

        let acumulador="";

        for(let i = 0; i < longitudCadena; i++){
            // console.log(i);
            if (i % 4 == 0 && i>0){
                acumulador+=("-"+string_[i]);
            }else{
                acumulador+=(string_[i]);
            }            
        }
        return console.log(acumulador);
    }else{
        // En este caso tendrias que realizar otra distribucion de los "-"
        console.log("No es Multiplo 4");
    }
}

cadenaConCaracteres(cadenaCaracteres);
```